# touch up inside (@IBAction) does not work with UIButton subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created a subclass of `UIButton`:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CheckboxButton: UIButton {

@IBInspectable var checkboxBackgroundColor: UIColor = Project.Color.baseGray
@IBInspectable var textColor: UIColor = Project.Color.mainDarkText

@IBInspectable var checkboxHighlightedBackgroundColor: UIColor = Project.Color.main
@IBInspectable var highlightedTextColor: UIColor = Project.Color.mainBrightText

// MARK: - Properties
var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        changeState()
    }
}


// MARK: - Overrides
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

    if isChecked {
        isChecked = false
    } else {
        isChecked = true
    }

    return false
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    changeState()
}


// MARK: - @IBActions



// MARK: - Functions
private func setupView() {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    changeState()
}

private func changeState() {
    if isChecked {
        backgroundColor = checkboxHighlightedBackgroundColor
        self.setTitleColor(highlightedTextColor, for: .normal)
    } else {
        backgroundColor = checkboxBackgroundColor
        self.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
    }
}
 }
```

Now I added a button inside the storyboard and gave it the class `CheckboxButton`. Everything works. Then I added an `IBAction` like this:

```
@IBAction func pointBtnTapped(_ sender: CheckboxButton) {
    print("tapped")
    selectButton(withNumber: sender.tag)
}
```

But this doesn't work (nothing prints out). It works with a normal button, but not if the button is the subclass `CheckboxButton`. Do you have any ideas?

Edit: screenshots
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewicc349ag9l6y2/Screenshot%202016-10-06%2023.41.39.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxevzscueproivc/Screenshot%202016-10-06%2023.42.33.png?dl=0
(couldn't embed them here. Don't know why)

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work if you change the declared type of `sender` to `AnyObject`?

Comment: And when you say it doesn't work, does it crash, print a warning/error, or fail silently? Also, if you change the type or name of a button in Storyboard, you have to redraw the `IBAction` connection and delete any stale ones. Does the little circle next to the method show as filled in?

Comment: No, `AnyObject`doesn't work. I mean, nothing happens. It doesn't crash, it just doesn't print anything. Sorry, if my text was misleading. I checked the circle, it's filled in

Comment: Probably we'll need screen captures of the Attributes Inspector, Identity Inspector, and Outlets Inspector of the button in question.

Comment: You have overridden `beginTracking` and returned false, so the control won't track the touch beyond the initial touch down inside.

Comment: That could be it. One second, I'll try EDIT: it worked :) You wanna post this as answer? I'll accept it

Comment: Also, touchUpInside is probably the wrong action to use with this sort of control. `valueChanged` would be more appropriate; you will need to fire this action yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You broke `UIButton` by overriding `beginTracking()` and always returning false. This brainwashes the button into thinking it's never being clicked.

What was your intent there? In any case, return `true` there and your code will fire the `@IBAction`.

EDIT: You're overthinking the issue by using a low-level method meant for highly customized behavior such as non-rectangular buttons. You just need:

[How to use UIButton as Toggle Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882857/how-to-use-uibutton-as-toggle-button)