# iOS UIButtons - Toggle backgrounds when 1 is selected, others are not

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I have multiple buttons, representing data input (scores). When 1 button is selected, change it's background to 1 colour. All other buttons should be set to a different colour, showing which is currently selected (toggled).

I have used the info from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882857/how-to-use-uibutton-as-toggle-button) to implement an @IBAction function to change the button. I used the Swift v4 reply / solution as the basis, essentially a single function as:

```swift
    @IBAction func buttonPressToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        if sender.isSelected {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        } else {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }
```

All buttons use the same function, so I can target the button through the `sender` local variable. I can also use the `tag` property, but I haven't done anything with this currently.

What is missing with this is to "reset" any other button's state / background colour, as it is no longer selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.buttons.forEach {
            $0.backgroundColor = ($0 == sender) ? UIColor.orange : UIColor.green
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, simple solution. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var collectionOfButtons: Array<UIButton>?
    
    private let selectionColor = UIColor.orange
    private let nonSelectedColor = UIColor.green
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let buttons = collectionOfButtons else { return }
        
        for btn in buttons {
            if btn.tag == sender.tag {
                btn.backgroundColor = selectionColor
            } else {
                btn.backgroundColor = nonSelectedColor
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically we store the outlet for each button in an array and if one button got selected, we loop through this array and check, whether the current button (`btn`) was the selected one and if so, we set it's `backgroundColor` to a different one.
So for this approach the buttons should been taged.

I have uploaded my sample project: https://github.com/finebel/ToggleButtons